# org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException:Invalid property of bean class [SPServiceForm]: Invalid array index in property path authLevel[0]

Tags: spring, jsp, exception

I have a property in model or bean classs which i am using in jsp and while submitting the form getting below exception

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'authLevel[0]' of bean class [in.cdac.epramaan.ui.sp.model.SPServiceForm]: Invalid array index in property path 'authLevel[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

**SPServiceForm**

```
private String[] authLevel;

public String[] getAuthLevel() {
    return authLevel;
}

public void setAuthLevel(String[] authLevel) {
    this.authLevel = authLevel;
}
```

In jsp :

```
    <form:checkbox path="authType" value="${authLevelFactor.key}" abel="${authLevelFactor.key}"/>
                            <ul class="verticalRadios">
    <form:radiobuttons path="authLevel[${seq1.index}]" items="${authLevelFactor.value}" itemValue="levelId" itemLabel="levelDesc" element="li"/>
                            </ul>
```

When i submit the form it is throwing above error what is issue with authLevel property(this is radio)
I have create string array in model in jsp i assigned list to it and it will iterate in for each loop also

below is jsp **exception**

```
message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'authLevel[0]' of bean class [in.cdac.epramaan.ui.sp.model.SPServiceForm]: Invalid array index in property path 'authLevel[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'authLevel[0]' of bean class [in.cdac.epramaan.ui.sp.model.SPServiceForm]: Invalid array index in property path 'authLevel[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
root cause
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'authLevel[0]' of bean class [in.cdac.epramaan.ui.sp.model.SPServiceForm]: Invalid array index in property path 'authLevel[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:980)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:922)
    org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:728)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:106)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
root cause   
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Native Method)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:977)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:922)
    org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:728)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:106)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: How do you initialize your String array exactly ?

Comment: i have no idea about the size of string array ,size is dynamic so how can i delcare the size?

Comment: Hum nope, the size of an array in Java is defined at initialization but isn't dynamic after this point (not like a collection). You can initialize an array like *String[] authLevel = new String[10];* for an array of size 10 for example. If your array grows beyond that size, you'll get a *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found soultion please see below for code
```

```
<form:radiobuttons path="authChainCodes[${seq1.index}].levelId" items="${authLevelFactor.value}" itemValue="levelId" itemLabel="levelDesc" element="li"
                        disabled="${!authLevelFactor.value[seq1.index].levelActive}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is looking for a property with name authLevel[0] which is not defined in the class from the statement "Invalid property 'authLevel[0]' of bean class". Also the size of property is not defined so make sure before fetching you are setting the data in the property.

Comment: I have used list as form property instead of string array but getting below error   Illegal attempt to get property 'authLevel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'authLevel' of bean class [in.cdac.epramaan.ui.sp.model.SPServiceForm]: Could not instantiate property type [java.lang.Integer] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Integer
 org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:848)